# How to NOT print first 2 values in $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

I have a page to view cart items which I bring there using `$_SESSION[$name]`. I used `$_SESSION` earlier also to save user id and user name. Now when I try to print the products on Cart page, it shows all products but also shows user id and name as they are also stored in `$_SESSION`.

```php
$sno=1;
foreach ($_SESSION as $products) {
    //print_r($products);
    $p=0;
    $q=0;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".($sno++)."</td>";
    /*This if to prevent the error of Invalid arguments passed in foreach because it should always be an array to be used in foreach*/
    if(is_array($products)){
        foreach($products as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 3) {
                echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                $q=$value;
            } else if ($key == 2) {
                echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                $p = $value ;
            }else if ($key == 1) {
                echo "<td><img class='cart-img' src='".$value."'/></td>";
            }else if ($key == 0) {
                echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
            }
        }

    }
    echo "<td>".($p*$q)."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='event' value='Update' class='btn btn-warning'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='event' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Here is my code. and I am attaching the Snapshot of my page.
[View Cart Page with 2 extra rows on top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKXcn.jpg)

Kindly help to remove the first 2 rows. `print_r()` of `$_SESSION` also on top of the image.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

try something like below

```
$sno=1;
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $products) {
   if($key < 2){
      continue;
   }
// further your logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used it and it kinda made all products disappear. Maybe its coz u dnt have all of the code. The other comment works for me. :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. Just set the `is_array` check at the beginning.

```
$sno=1;

foreach ($_SESSION as $products)
{
    //print_r($products);
    if(!is_array($products))
        continue;

    $p=0;
    $q=0;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".($sno++)."</td>";
    /*This if to prevent the error of Invalid arguments passed in foreach because it should always be an array to be used in foreach*/

    foreach($products as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key == 3)
        {
            echo "
            <td>".$value."</td>"; $q=$value;
        }
        else if ($key == 2)
        {
            echo "
            <td>".$value."</td>";
            $p = $value;
        }
        else if ($key == 1)
        {
            echo "
            <td><img class='cart-img' src='".$value."' /></td>";
        }
        else if ($key == 0)
        {
            echo "
            <td>".$value."</td>";
        }
    }

    echo "<td>".($p*$q)."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='event' value='Update' class='btn btn-warning'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='event' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. That saved me from pulling my hair out. Works perfect now. Yay!! :)